# Pyglet handlers and deleted objects

Tags: python, pyglet

In my game with Python and pyglet, I have groups which propagate events downward to its members:

```
class Group(EventDispatcher):
    def __init__(self):
        self.members = []
    def add(self, member):
        self.members.append(member)
        self.push_handlers(member)
    def remove(self, member):
        self.members.remove(member)
        # and then what???
Group.register_event('on_event')
```

If I `del` all my references to a member and remove() it, will the handlers in Group prevent the object from being garbage collected?  Will the handlers just disappear (weakref)?  If not, how can I clean up the handlers?

EDIT: I ran I test session to see what happens:

```
>>> from pyglet.event import EventDispatcher
>>> class Group(EventDispatcher):
...  pass
... 
>>> Group.register_event_type('on_tick')
'on_tick'
>>> g = Group()
>>> class Members:
...  def on_tick(self):
...   print('tick')
... 
>>> m = Members()
>>> g.push_handlers(m)
>>> g.dispatch_event('on_tick')
tick
>>> del m
>>> g.dispatch_event('on_tick')
tick
>>> class B:
...  def on_tick(self):
...   print(self.x)
... 
>>> m = B()
>>> g.push_handlers(m)
>>> g.dispatch_event('on_tick')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/site-packages/pyglet/event.py", line 355, in dispatch_event
    if handler(*args):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in on_tick
AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'x'
>>> m.x = 3
>>> g.dispatch_event('on_tick')
3
tick
>>> del m
>>> g.dispatch_event('on_tick')
3
tick
```

So I guess EventDispatcher still keeps a reference to the handler.  Thus, the question becomes how do I clean up the handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EventDispatcher.remove_handlers is the opposite of push_handlers.  So calling remove_handlers(m) then del m will allow m to be garbage collected.